# How can I pass a matrix by a function?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to pass a matrix (5000x121) by a function (an sum of exponential distribution) and save the results in another matrix. It is returning a key error and I can´t solve it.

Any idea to help me resolve this problem?

I appreciate any help.

First rows and columns of the matrix. This is also a matrix with random numbers.

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 10,15 | 13,7425 | 17,755375 |
| 2 | 5 | 9,55 | 12,8725 | 16,928875 |
| 3 | 5 | 9,75 | 14,7625 | 18,924375 |
| 4 | 5 | 9,95 | 14,2525 | 18,439875 |
| 5 | 5 | 8,85 | 12,9075 | 18,262125 |

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

A = pd.read_excel("matrix.xlsx")

num_rows, num_cols = A.shape

a = np.zeros((num_rows, num_cols))

for i in range(num_rows):
    for j in range(num_cols):
        a[i][j] = sum(np.random.exponential(5000, int(A[i][j])))
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3080             try:
-> 3081                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3082             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 121

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-d7182902d41c> in <module>
      9 for i in range(sim):
     10     for j in range(t):
---> 11         a[i][j] = sum(np.random.exponential(5000, int(A[i][j])))

~\anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3022             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3023                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3024             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3025             if is_integer(indexer):
   3026                 indexer = [indexer]

~\anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3081                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3082             except KeyError as err:
-> 3083                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3084 
   3085         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 121
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: Please provide an insight into how the matrix A looks like. Especially check the 121st row or column in the matrix.

Comment: The problem is with indexing the `dataframe`: `A[i][j]`.  Look at the traceback.  Do you see things like `pandas/.../frame.py`, `_getitem__`, and `get_loc`.  That's pandas trying to use your index on a dataframe.  You haven't gotten anywhere close to passing a matrix to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You get a pandas error (Keyerror) when it tries to search for key 121 and doesn't find it. Since we don't know the content of "matrix.xlsx" it is hard to locate the problem, it'd depend on the index and name of the columns of the object A, buy you can use [A.iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to access specific locations using integers. In this case: A.iloc[i, j]

Also if you want to save to the the numpy array a, the more natural way of expressing that would be with a[row, column] instead of a[row][column].